# Search events by extended properties in Google Calendar API with emulating "OR" statement

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to search my Google events by "sharedExtendedProperty" values.

The doc for it is [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list).

I have a few props attached to some of my events. 
e.g.

```
account: 123456
note: 654321
```

I can easily search by one of the property as well as by both properties. 
However, I can't find a way to search for this event with OR statement. 
Is there a way I say that event that I search should contain either:

```
account: 123456
```

Or:

```
note: 654321
```

There is no info about it in the documentation. 
If I search by both, then it searches for the full much and I don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not supported unfortunately but here's what I would do

1. Create two instances of the Runnable class and start them at the exact same time for the best performance results.
2. Start Thread 1 immediately and perform the first search: `account: 123456`
3. Start Thread 2 immediately and perform the second search: `note: 654321`
4. Merge both results into a map. You could do this (N+M) -> O(N) by looping over both arrays and blind inserting them both into the map by Event ID. Even cooler would be to use `ConcurrentMap` and have both threads insert into the map at the same time which should get you close to (N+M)/2 -> O(N) runtime.

Here's some psuedo-code. It definitely needs tweaking as I haven't used Java in a really long time unfortunately.

```
latch = New CountDownLatch(2)
map = New ConcurrentMap()

thread1 = New Runnable(latch) { 
results = gcal.Search("account" = "123456") 
for result in results:
    map.add(result)
latch.countDown()
};

thread2 = New Runnable(latch) {
results = gcal.Search("note" = "654321") 
for result in results:
    map.add(result)
latch.countDown()
}; 

thread1.Start();
thread2.Start();
latch.await();

// map will be full at this point in time and have no over-lapping values
```